# Cannot alter user in MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I have an issue with connection to MySQL database.

Internet says that error `Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'` can be fixed with `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '123';`.

The issue is that this command doesn't work. `ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '123';` also doesn't work.

First command affects 0 rows and has an error `1 factor authentication method does not match against authentication policy. Please refer @@authentication_policy system variable.`, second one returns an error `Operation ALTER USER failed`. Of course I'm replacing `123` with my real admin password.

I'm absolutely out of ideas, I hope I can get some clues why this command doesn't work.

Edit

I think the only solution is to uninstall newest MySQL version and install an older one that actually works. Topic closed.

Comment: Are you actually trying to use that specific plugin to hash the password?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález no. I'm trying to connect to database for 4 hours and it tries all possible things to stop me, but I have time. I have also tried to create new user with mysql_native_password but it also has 0 rows affected, 1 warnings.

Comment: If you don't care about the plugin, why don't you skip that part and see what happens? `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123';`

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález this command has 1 warning and it doesn't fix the issue `1 factor authentication method does not match against authentication policy. Please refer @@authentication_policy system variable.`. I cannot skip that part because it loads by default.

Comment: What does your `@@authentication_policy` system variable contain? If you don't have a GUI client, you can run `select @@authentication_policy`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález it contains `caching_sha2_password,,`

Comment: You seem to have an [authentication policy](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multifactor-authentication.html) that requires a plugin that is not installed. This is a server administration issue that's beyond my area of expertise. Perhaps you can edit the question and provide information about your operating system and how you installed MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to FLUSH PRIVILEGES after a user update command.

Comment: Doesn't change anything in my case.